# Guide is not spawning

Tags: terraria

I have a 20-room house that is close to a 'spawn corruption'. Only 6/20 rooms were taken.

NPCs are not spawning, like the guide, nurse, and tax collector.

Is it because my house is too close to corruption or something else?

Comment: In the housing interface, you should be able to hit a button named "Check Housing". When your inside vacant houses, what does it say when you hit this button? The message can be cryptic, but can still eliminate a lot of the potential issues. Also, if you could provide a screenshot of the housing, this might help other users confirm that other features are in place.

Comment: It's probably too close to the corruption. Since that stops housing from being valid.

Comment: @Frank Tis funny how many questions get asked that are duplicates of that.

Comment: @Waterseas, looking at the question, I think I can see why. There are a few common issues I find people have, building houses, that are not quite covered in any answer there. For example, there is a way to check the conditions of a house in both the console and computer version. I also find the biggest drawback is the ease at missing a single tile of walling - which can still look complete, if you are not looking at it, closely.

Comment: @Timelord64 You can leave up to four spaces of walling open, creating sort of a window, and yet still have valid housing.